# Getting dropdown selected value on change using DOJO script

Tags: javascript, dojo

Hi I am working on DOJO website and I need to get the dropdown selected value without redirecting to another page using DOJO script or Plain javascript(No jquery, because dojo website not supporting Jquery).

Here is my scenerio

View account
      View payment
      address change
     FAQ

Comment: be more explicit post some of your html / dojo code , and whah you mean by -> without redirect !

Answer (score 0):

You want the value selected from a drop down box but the act of selecting the value in the first place causes a redirect? You mean the values are coded as links? If so then you need to find the code where the value is used as a link and write some condition to get the value rather than let the click redirect.

If you just want the currently selected value then you need to find the same code, where it was processed as a link, and set a variable there that you can use for your purposes.